# How can setup AspectJ for web application

Tags: aspectj

I'm new to AspectJ and want to integrate AspectJ advices in existing web application running on weglogic server.

can anyone please let me know what all is required to do so.
I was looking into the documentation, there is no clear instruction.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just start weblogic with the waver agent:

-javaagent:/libs/aspectj-1.7.2/aspectjweaver.jar

do not forget to include the META-INF/aop.xml in the classpath

It's also very important that the Class Loader used to load the aop.xml file is the ear-class loader because otherwithe you have to replicate the aop.xml in every WAR or EJB module (each one have it's own classloader)
To achieve this just put the aop.xml file at:
    xxxEar/EarContent/APP-INF/classes/META-INF/aop.xml